# Display two fields as mandatory based on selected radio button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this radio button in HTML.

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
  <input id="vendor" type="radio" ng-model="c.data.cvendor" name="customerType" value="cvendor" ng-true-value="CVendor" ng-false-value="false">
  ${CVendor}
  </label> 
</div>
```

Once this option checked, the two fields below should be displayed and are mandatory. How can I achieve this in HTML?

```
<div class="form-group is-required">
  <label for="fieldb">${FieldB}:</label>
  <input type="text" class="my-input" ng-model="c.data.fieldb" id="fieldb" placeholder="Enter Field B">
</div>
<div class="form-group is-required">
  <label for="fieldc">${FieldC}:</label>
  <input type="text" class="my-input" ng-model="c.data.fieldc" id="fieldc" placeholder="Enter Field C">
</div>
```

Comment: Check this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-required)

Comment: is those field hidden by default?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `ng-if="c.data.cvendor==='cvendor'"`.

Radio button sets `c.data.cvendor` to 'cvendor'. Thus you can control the display of two input fields via `ng-if`

As for the fields to be mandatory, you can try `ng-required="true"`.

```
    <div class="form-group is-required" ng-if="c.data.cvendor==='cvendor'">
     <label for="fieldb">${FieldB}:</label>
     <input type="text" class="my-input" ng-model="c.data.fieldb" id="fieldb" placeholder="Enter Field B" ng-required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group is-required" ng-if="c.data.cvendor==='cvendor'">
     <label for="fieldc">${FieldC}:</label>
     <input type="text" class="my-input" ng-model="c.data.fieldc" id="fieldc" placeholder="Enter Field C" ng-required="true">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **ng-required**. Based on 'c.data.fieldb' value it will become mandatory or non-mandatory. Similarly,  for hide and show you can use **ng-show** / **ng-hide**.

```
<div class="form-group is-required">
     <label for="fieldb">${FieldB}:</label>
     <input type="text" class="my-input" ng-model="c.data.fieldb" id="fieldb" placeholder="Enter Field B" ng-required="c.data.cvendor == 'CVendor'">
</div>

<div class="form-group is-required">
     <label for="fieldc">${FieldC}:</label>
     <input type="text" class="my-input" ng-model="c.data.fieldc" id="fieldc" placeholder="Enter Field C" ng-required="c.data.cvendor == 'CVendor'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code**

```js
var checkBox;
function DemoFunctin() {
 checkBox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
var textInput1 = document.querySelector('input[name="first"]');
var textInput2 = document.querySelector('input[name="second"]');


    if (textInput1.hasAttribute('required') !== true && textInput2.hasAttribute('required') !== true) {
       
        textInput1.setAttribute('required','required');
        textInput2.setAttribute('required','required');
         
    }

    else {
        textInput1.removeAttribute('required'); 
        textInput2.removeAttribute('required'); 
        
    }
 
}
if(checkBox){
checkBox.addEventListener('change',toggleRequired,false);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h3>display-two-fields-as-mandatory-based-on-selected-radio-button</h3>


<form>
<p><input type="radio" onclick="DemoFunctin();"/>Check Me to make the Text Box a Required Field</p>
<input type="text" name="first"/>
<input type="text" name="second"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```